# Change Spinner color arrow

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-spinner

I want to customize the spinner background and change his arrow color, when runnig the app on my phone, i got two arrows instead of one .

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE07T.jpg

The test layout ::

```
        <Spinner   
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/array_name"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        app:theme="@style/SpinnerColor"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#a4c2f7"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#a4c2f7" />
```

The style layout :: ( The style )

```
    <style name="SpinnerColor" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#F00</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a spinner with one arrow on the right. This is how I did it:

First download an Arrow Icon. I got one from [icons8](https://icons8.com)

Now create a new file named 'spinner_bg.xml' in the 'drawable' folder & add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#2f6699" />
<item><layer-list>
    <item><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#2f6699" />


        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
    </shape></item>
    <item ><bitmap android:gravity="right|center" android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_drop_down_black_18dp" /> //the arrow icon we downloaded previously
    </item>
</layer-list></item>

</selector>
```

Then in the Spinner code in the xml file, set the xml bg file we created as the background - `android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"`

This should give you the result you need!